# VNRecognizeTextRequest Text Detection Line Break

Tags: swift, vision

Using Vision.
Is there a way to detect line breaks in VNRecognizeTextRequest?

This is a part of my code:

```
let text = observation.compactMap({
                $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string
            }).joined(separator: "\n")
```

the result of a multiline text ignores the real line breaks in the image.
example:

[image]

Comment: Each text observation result should be limited to 1 line

Comment: Answer has been edited @aheze

Comment: @HassanTaleb did you find out a way to detect line breaks? I'm stuck with the same problem.